# How to concatenate a variable and string as a table name

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to concatenate a sting to a variable as a table name.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @ENTITY VARCHAR(50)
SET @ENTITY = 'NATURAL'

SELECT * 
INTO @ENTITY+'_COMPLETENESS_NAME'
FROM TABLE1
```

As a result I would like to create a table, named `[NATURAL_COMPLETENESS_NAME]`

I am currently using MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);

SET @sql = '
SELECT * 
INTO ' + @ENTITY + '_COMPLETENESS_NAME
FROM TABLE1';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note:  You cannot use a parameter for the table name, because you can't use parameters for table, column, schema, or database identifiers.  To be safe, you might want to use:

```
SET @sql = '
SELECT * 
INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@ENTITY + '_COMPLETENESS_NAME') +
FROM TABLE1';
```

This protects you if `@ENTITY` has unusual characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @ENTITY VARCHAR(50)
SET @ENTITY = 'NATURAL'

EXEC ('SELECT  * INTO '+ @ENTITY + '_COMPLETENESS_NAME FROM TABLE1')
```